# How to set up development environment for SharePoint in Azure Management Portal

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

I have been trying to setup SharePoint 2013 along with Visual Studio for learning purpose in Azure Management Portal.

Can anyone please explain how to set up SharePoint environment with Visual Studio for learning some development activities.